# Handling inputs centrally in Java

Tags: java, input, frameworks, mouseevent, keyevent

I am working on the framework for a basic interactive program. In it, I have an InputHandler class that is executed every time the keyPressed or keyReleased event (specified in the main class) occurs. The InputHandler has a constructor, which is loaded into the main class; however, I wish for other objects (such as the Player class) to be able to have their own behaviors when keys are pressed. Is there a way to have a single Array or ArrayList that contains the values of keys pressed that can be loaded by another class without initializing a new instance of the InputListener for each one? Please let me know if further clarification is needed.

Here is the code for my InputHandler class:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class InputListener {
    private ArrayList<Integer> keysPressed = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int mouseXPos, mouseYPos;
    public InputListener(){
    }
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        keysPressed.add(e.getKeyCode());
    }
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e){
    }

    public ArrayList<Integer> getKeysPressed(){
        return keysPressed;
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        mouseXPos = e.getX();
        mouseYPos = e.getY();
    }

    public int getMouseXPos(){
        return mouseXPos;
    }

    public int getMouseYPos(){
        return mouseYPos;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make it observable and just register each needed class like player as observer. so in case of an input event all observer classes are notified about the key pressed.

take a look at the various tutorials about the observer pattern like [here](http://www.javabeginners.de/Design_Patterns/Observer_-Pattern.php).